# Como redirecionar para uma pagina com node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirecionamento, express.js, redirecionamento-de-url

Sei fazer isso mais com uma rota, porem eu quero fazer algo como:

```
app.redirect(url);
```

e não:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.redirect(url);
});
```

alguem pode me ajudar?
vlw , e obgd!

Comment: Mas qual o problema de usar res.redirect() ?

Comment: O problema é que eu quero fazer isso quando não for possivel conectar com o banco de dados, ai ele é redirecionado para uma pagina que diz isso para o usuario

Comment: Resolveu essa questão?

Comment: Você quer redirecionar para todas as rotas? Parece que você quer usar um  middleware.